Why LOUDS is considered succinct coding?
LOUDS encoding is widely cited as succinct, e.g., in the papers, in Github repos, etc.
It is straightforward that LOUDS takes 2n bits for encoding an ordered tree with n vertices.
But I found few formula counts trees like $4^n$ .
For example, Cayley's Formula counts $n^{n-2}$ labeled trees with n nodes, which is obviously not the correct counting formula.
Then it comes to my question: why is it considered as succinct?
Or which counting formula does it correspond to?

The number of ordered trees on $n$ vertices is $C_{n-1}$. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics .

@EmilJeřábek Oh thank you again!  Now I know that what puzzled me is the difference between labeled and ordered, I found these words are really misused sometimes. Once it is spotted out, the question solved.
